# How to extract only number if every number is displayed in second line

Tags: java, arrays

I want to extract only number that number is displayed in every second line.

```
Moapa, NV
89025 US
Palmer, MA
01069 US
Hill Air Force Base, UT
84056 US
Liberty, OH
45044 US
Mystic, IA
52574 US
Loveland, CO
80537 US
Boise, ID
83714 US
Croton, NY
10520 US
Bloomington, IL
61705 US
Hidalgo, TX US
Morrisville, PA
19067 US
presidio, TX
79845 US
DOUGLASSVILLE, PA
19518 US
Sutherlin, VA
24594 US
Brighton, CO
80601 US
Indianapolis, IN
46204 US
MARIETTA and ASHLAND, OH
44805 US
Sutherlin, VA
24594 US
Frostburg, MD
21532 US
Sutherlin, VA
24594 US
Gridiron, TX
77054 US
Nacogdoches, TX
75964 US
Sun Valley, CA
91352 US
Eagle Pass, TX
78852 US
```

I have used this

```
int value=Integer.parseInt(str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
```

but after printing total 9 number getting an error "java.lang.NumberFormatException"

Please help me to print only number.

Comment: Skip every second line in your loop.

Comment: Yup, "" is not a valid integer. You should find another strategy (possible hint: `Pattern`)

Answer (score 3):

It is not advisable to convert US postal codes to integer values. While it is true that they are strings consisting of decimal digits they should be treated as Strings.

Consider:

```
Palmer, MA
01069 US
```

The integer value from parseInt will be 1069, and if this is printed it will be four digits, 1069, and the US Mail might be perplexed.

USe

```
String value = str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```

and test its length.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting exception because after printing *9 number*s there are *consecutive 2 lines* that holds no number that arises the Exception. Rather depending on the line number pattern you should check for a **Valid line** to print

Iterate each line and match against pattern to check if its valid line

```
if (line.matches("^\\d+.*")) {
  int value = Integer.parseInt(line.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
  /* Do whatever you like to do */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8 you can use :

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("fileName.txt"))) {

    stream.filter(line -> line.matches("^\\d+.*"))//filter only the lines start with a number
            .map(line -> Integer.parseInt(line.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "")))//replace all non digit and parse it to Integer
            .forEach(System.out::println);//print the result

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

Like you can collect the result in a List of Integers :

```
List<Integer> listNumbers = stream.filter(line -> line.matches("^\\d+.*"))
        .map(line -> Integer.parseInt(line.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "")))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Note : Like @laune mention in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47959272/5558072), you will lost some information in US postal code if parse it, Instead use Strings like this :

```
List<String> listNumbers = stream.filter(line -> line.matches("^\\d{5}.*"))// Filter the codes start with 5 digits
        .map(line -> line.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: why not @laune, the OP want this, no?

Comment: These Java 8 sauces are yummy !

Comment: If you think that it is all right to let him make a mistake: then let him.

Answer (score 0):

You have missing data by the line.

'Hidalgo, TX US'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the data in a file.

- Read the file line by line.
- Split the line by the " " character and get your number.
- If the line has a number it will parse it, else it will throw a number format exception handle it gracefully.
- Repeat this for all the lines in the file.

Code:

```
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class PrintSecondLine {
    public static void main() throws IOException{
        File file = new File("/tmp/myFile.txt");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(file);
        while(keyboard.hasNextLine()){
            String line = keyboard.nextLine();
            try{
               int number = Integer.parseInt(line.split(" ")[0]);
               System.out.println(number);
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException exception){                   
            }
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading file that contain the text a line by line,
you have to check if the string is empty or not before parsing.

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
if (!str.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```